# How to draw a thermal graphic in C#?

Tags: c#, graphics

I want to draw a thermal graphic in C#. This graphic likes [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEcJc.jpg).

I found a charting library [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/). But the library can't do this.

Any suggestions?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Google search on **C# heatmap** found this website:

http://dylanvester.com/post/Creating-Heat-Maps-with-NET-20-%28C-Sharp%29.aspx

Hope this will help you getting started.